# Marking "example usage" in code documentation

Tags: documentation, javadoc, doxygen, documentation-generation

What is the best practice of placing example usage in code documentation? Is there a standardised way? With an @usage or @notes? Do document generators tend to support this?

I know this question should depend on the documentation generator. However, I'm trying to get a habit of using a commenting style for doc generation before getting into the idiosyncrasies of each generator; seems there are more similarites than differences.

I've experimented with Doxygen & often use AS3, JS, PHP, Obj-C, C++.

For example:

```
/**
 * My Function
 * @param object id  anObject 
 * @usage a code example here... 
 */
function foo(id) {

}
```

or

```
/**
 * My Function
 * @param object id  anObject 
 * @notes a code example here, maybe?
 */
function foo(id) {

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doxygen has a command *@example*, and there are a lot of options for configuring example source paths.

I think there are a common set of commands between Doxygen and other documentation tools, but they are too few for good documenting. You need to specilize to get the best from a specific tool.
I like Doxygen, since it is opensource and highly configurable. But it is only my opinion about it.

Maybe you could configure doxygen with *@xrefitem* aliases to allow parsing documentation comments defined with other documentation tools.

Comment: great thanks – this has got me on the right path. it's a shame @example can't include inline code examples.